# Fishpig WordPress Integration Homepage Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, third-party-module, wordpress, blog

I can't get the Fishpig WordPress extension to work no matter what I do. The link to the extension is here:

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

I've installed it and configured it all correctly. The weird thing is that I can go to the post pages fine at the correct url:

http://www.example.com/blog/post-name/

I'm trying to put the whole blog at the 'blog' subdirectory. The issue is that all pages work except for the main page:

http://www.example.com/blog/

Every time I try to visit it, I get redirected to the homepage. I think it's conflicting with the core Magento blog (which I've disabled) because when I enable it, the link http://www.example.com/blog/ opens but it opens to the blank Lorem Ipsum blog through Magento. I've changed the main URL for this blog to 'http://www.example.com/news/' which also works (both the /news/ and /blog/ work). I was thinking the name 'blog' was conflicting or something along those lines.

So then I tried to change the path to the blog to:

http://www.example.com/site-blog/

But when I had that all set up, the posts worked with this structure:

http://www.example.com/site-blog/post-name/

But when I tried to go to the main homepage, it gave me a 404 error.

I'm out of ideas as to what's going on. Any ideas on what I can do to just get something up and running? Thanks for your help.

Comment: have try with index.php http://www.example.com/index.php/site-blog/post-name/

Comment: Hi @AmitBera, I should have specified that the permalinks have all been changed so we're not using the default index.php in the URLs. The rest of the site is fine without index.php in the URL.